# MongoDB replica set have the same config but got rep lag on a node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image: MMS]

All node have run with the same config.

When I send high write load to my replica set I found one of my secondary node have high Replication Lag.

In Mongodb client(nodejs mongodb v2.0.42) I connect to replica set with readPreference=secondaryPreferred

It should have the same behaviour in both secondary.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that one of my server doesn't have same Read Ahead as others.

So I follow this [instruction](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/)

Problem solve!